# Setting cookies when using Ajax and JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, cookies

Looking for an accepted practice for setting browser cookies within a JSON and Ajax based web application.

The browser seems to not accept cookies from the server for JSON requests. This leaves me with two options that I can see:

1. When doing operations that need to involve cookies, do not use JSON requests, but rather evaluate the JSON after the text gets to the client using `JSON.parse()`
2. Send the cookie information from the server to the client via JSON, then use the browser to set the cookie instead of through server heads. Does this also mean that the cookie information will have to be read on the client and sent back to the server via JSON because the browser will not send cookie information via AJAX JSON requests as well?

My inclination is to go with option #1, but these both seem pretty crappy options. Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are sent only if the Domain property matches the domain you are on.

So for example you set a coockie with the domain '.domain.com'. Any requests made to domain.com or any subdomain will contain the cookie, but only that.

For request to other domains you need the coockie set serverside or if the user interacts with a page that sets a cookie for that domain.

2 simple ways to set the cookie that came to mind are:

1. Obviously, make a ajax call to a script to set the cookie
2. Do something like this:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain2.com/cookie_login_page.php?username=johnsmith&hash=1614aasdfgh213g"></script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    // ... setCookie stuff
    echo 'var cookie_set = true;';
?>
```